# TensorFlow: How to use tf.train.SummaryWriter inside supervisor.loop (0.12.0rc1)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am using `tf.train.Supervisor` to manage my session. I am already using the `summary_writer` in the supervisor to write some summaries. I would however, at other intervals, like to write another set of summaries. As fare as I can see the easiest way is to use a `supervisor.loop`. What I was is basically:

Pseudo code:

```
summary_merged_valid = tf.summary.merge(summary_ops_valid)
valid_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logdir + '/valid')
global_step = slim.get_or_create_global_step()

...

config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
with sv.managed_session(config=config) as sess:

    ...

    sv.loop(validation_interval,
        valid_writer.add_summary,
        (summary_merged_valid, global_step)
        )
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also provide your own summaries to Supervisor using

```
sv.summary_computed(sess, summary, global_step)
```

manually. One interesting thing that doesn't seem to be advertised too much is that you can group summaries into collections like so:

```
tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', p_lr, collections=['train'])
tf.summary.scalar('loss', t_loss, collections=['train', 'test'])
s_training = tf.summary.merge_all('train')
```

and then only write the `train` variables by fetching `s_training` and giving it to the the above function.

Comment: So, just to be clear, for the `sv.summary_computed` method, you would wrap that in a `sc.loop`?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow documents this [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/distributed_execution#Supervisor.__init__), under **Launching additional services**:

> Example: Start a thread to print losses. We want this thread to run every 60 seconds, so we launch it with sv.loop().
>
> ```
> sv = Supervisor(logdir='/tmp/mydir') with sv.managed_session(FLAGS.master) as sess:
>     sv.loop(60, print_loss, (sess)) while not sv.should_stop(): 
>         sess.run(my_train_op)
> ```

See answer by @sunside for good tips on how to do this in a smart way.